# The parent package in SSIS fails with the following

Tags: ssis

Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '08S01'. Native Error Code: 30046. [SAP][ASE ODBC Driver]Connection to the server has been lost. Connection died while reading from socket. Socket returned error code 10054. ERRNO returned 0. Check the server to determine the status of any open transactions.

Answer (score 0):

This message points to problems with SAP. Contact SAP administrator and ask to check it there were any problem with SAP instance. You should also talk to network enigneer to verify if there was a problem with network connection.

On SSIS side everything looks fine.